# Which dependency is responsible for creation of tables from spring boot entities automatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring-boot project but I want it to migrate **entity classes** to database tables when I specify **@Table** and **@Entity** annotations. For now, I am creating the tables manually.

Below is my **HibernateJpaVendorAdapter**

```
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("spring.jpa.generate-ddl",env.getProperty("spring.jpa.generate-ddl"));
        properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
```

Below is **application.properties**

[image]

Comment: Please include the actual text your your application properties in your question. I can read what is in that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency in your class path and you have to set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `update` or `create` in your `application.properties`.

But it should not be used it production.

Comment: How do i  do that using adapter above?

Comment: What is the value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in your system? Try to set this value to `update` or `create`. `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` should be wrapper for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`.

Comment: I have updated as you suggested above but it is not creating new tables

Comment: Do you have `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` in your properties? Please try adding them.

Comment: I did **spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true** but still not creating or updating tables.